# [VHDL][Xilinx] Automatically Inserting Markers once self-checking testbench is complete?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

Do any of you know if there's a way to have the simulation insert markers in the Wave Window where *Notes, Warnings, Errors, or Failures* have occured after the test has run to completion?  This would just be convenient for whoever is checking it to quickly diagnose the issue.

Also, is there a way to export the info contained in the Console Window to say a server (or some other way for it to be documented) once testing has completed?  Whether the info was minor errors, failures, warnings, or a successful test?

Comment: Some simulators allow the insertion of markers via TCL commands. It should be possible to grep the simulator outputs in the console and throw add marker commands back to the simulator.

Comment: yes here's the syntax for adding a marker in the Command Window: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/ism_cl_wave_marker_add.htm                                                                                                                                                                                         But how do you incorprate that into your testbench?  Specifically so that when an error occurs, it grabs the time needed for the marker and puts the marker down?

Comment: Oh iSim ... a good way is to use e.g. Python which launches the simulation and processes the output. If a message occurs (there should be the time in the message text) a new command is send to iSim. I don't think it can be done from inside the simulator. iSim has no full TCL console just a few commands.

Comment: ah, dang.  That sounds very foreign to me...  I have visual sudio on my computer , so C++ and C# languages.    Is there a link you could send me where I could read up on how to do that

Comment: The language does not matter you can also use C#. Our [PoC-Library](http://www.github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) uses Python to control different simulators like iSim. You can find the code in the `py/` folder. Maybe it's easier for you to use C#, it can start processes with Process.Start(StartInfo). The resulting process instance offers access to std_in and std_out. Here is an example  -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx